# Transform List into a Matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, transform

I would like to transform the following data from a csv file into a matrix :
Initial csv data :

```
A,B
A,B
A,c
B,D
B,E
```

...
Matrix

```
  A B C D E
A 0 2 1 0 0
B 0 0 0 1 1
C....
D...
E....
```

I'm pretty sure there might be some easy way to do this whithout using any specific package. Any idea or links ?

Thanks in advance to the community

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `table`?

```
dta <- read.table(text='A,B
A,B
A,c
B,D
B,E', sep=',')

table(dta)
##    V2
## V1  B c D E
##   A 2 1 0 0
##   B 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Yes the table function seems to make it...will it create a column for "A" also ? i'm going to git it a try

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a you're looking to do a pivot table with count of each set? I might be easier to just create pivot table in excel and load it into R

Comment: This works fine thanks...just need to fill the colum with no values with 0....will use Na or NaN function. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise an empty matrix with the names from the file and then fill it :

```
data=read.csv("filename", header=F)
names = as.character(unique(unlist(data)))
nnames = length(names)

mm = matrix(0, ncol=nnames, nrow=nnames, dimnames=list(names, names))
for (rr in 1:nrow(data)) {
    e1 = as.character(data[rr,1])
    e2 = as.character(data[rr,2])
    mm[e1, e2] = mm[e1, e2] + 1
}
```